# CLICOLOR and LS_COLORS in bash

Tags: bash, settings, colors, display-settings

I have the following setup in .bashrc for coloring of listings.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.ogg=01;35:*.mp3=01;35:*.wav=01;35:';
```

[This site](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) shows the code for colors, and I want to change the directory color to `light color'. But making di as follows doesn't affect it.

di=04;94

The interesting thing is that even after my commenting out LS_COLORS, I can see colored output as long as I have CLICOLOR=1.

- What should I do to make directory color to Light blue (94)?
- What's it for CLICOLOR and LS_COLORS? Why coloring works without LS_COLORS?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are several different implementations of color for ls, and you've conflated some of them.

- On [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=1&format=html) and [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html), `ls` shows colors if the `CLICOLOR` environment variable is set or if `-G` is passed on the command line. The actual colors are configured through the `LSCOLORS` environment variable (built-in defaults are used if this variable is not set). To show directories in light blue, use

  ```
  export LSCOLORS=Exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
  ```
- With [GNU ls](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html), e.g. on Linux, `ls` shows colors if `--color` is passed on the command line. The actual colors are configured through the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, which can be set with the [`dircolors`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html) command (built-in defaults are used if this variable is not set).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you teach me what Exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad means?

Comment: @prosseek: See the man pages I've linked to. For example, the first two characters are the foreground and background for directories, `e` means dark blue, `E` means light blue, and `x` means default. `f` in the third position makes symbolic links magenta, and so on.

Comment: On these same line, how do I make `tree` show colors? Tree shows colors on my Debian machine but does not do so on my Mac. Environment variables are present for color as described above. So my Mac shows colors for any `ls` commands but not `tree`. I installed tree with brew.

Comment: @DanCat I don't know. `tree` and `ls` are unrelated utilities, there's no reason why settings for one would apply to the other. You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @DanCat having the same prob in my iterm2 even with `tree -C`. tried it in Mac terminal (el capitan) as `tree -C` and that worked. haven't determined the issue in iterm2 yet.

Comment: For the lazy folks (like me) here's a LSCOLORS generator https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

Comment: confusingly, you can end up using GNU `ls` on macOS if you activate a conda env that uses something like GNU coreutiles as a dependency

Answer (score 13):

> What's it for CLICOLOR and LS_COLORS? Why coloring works without LS_COLORS?

`CLICOLOR` will turn colors on or off. `LS_COLORS` is not required, and will let you customize the colors.

Note that on some operating systems (Like MacOSX and FreeBSD), the value is named `LSCOLORS`, not `LS_COLORS`.

I avoid setting the color using LS_COLORS, because then I need to apply that same color scheme on a hundred different computers and 10 different Un*xes. Instead, I modify the color in my Terminal program, which works the same on most Unix hosts.

Comment: I can confirm that MacOS is looking for `LSCOLORS`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want a wrapper script for ls that works on all systems, abstracting away these color differences etc. see: http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/l