# only show the source file and target linked file using `ls`

Tags: ls, symlink

I can show the target file that a link points to using `ls -l`:

```
snowch$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvn
lrwxr-xr-x  1 snowch  admin  29 12 Dec 08:58 /usr/local/bin/mvn -> ../Cellar/maven/3.2.3/bin/mvn
```

Is there a way to show less output without having to pipe through another command such as awk?  E.g:

```
snowch$ ls ?? /usr/local/bin/mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn -> ../Cellar/maven/3.2.3/bin/mvn
```

I'm running 3.2.53 on OS X 10.9.5.  The output from several commands is shown below:

```
snowch$ ls -H /usr/local/bin/mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn

snowch$ ls -L /usr/local/bin/mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn

snowch$ file /usr/local/bin/mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn: POSIX shell script text executable

snowch$ file -b /usr/local/bin/mvn
POSIX shell script text executable
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` unfortunately doesn't have an option to retrieve file attributes and display them in an arbitrary way. Some systems have separate commands for that (for instance GNU has a `stat` command or the functionality in GNU `find`).

On most modern systems, with most files, this should work though:

```
$ ln -s '/foo/bar -> baz' the-file
$ LC_ALL=C ls -ldn the-file | sed '
   1s/^\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{8\}//'
the-file -> /foo/bar -> baz
```

That works by removing the first 8 blank delimited fields of the first line of the output of `ls -l`. That should work except on systems where the gid is not displayed there or the first 2 fields are joined together when there's a large number of links.

With GNU `stat`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C stat -c '%N' the-file
'the-file' -> '/foo/bar -> baz'
```

With GNU `find`:

```
$ find the-file -prune \( -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n' -o -printf '%p\n' \)
the-file -> /foo/bar -> baz
```

With FreeBSD/OS/X stat:

```
f=the-file
if [ -L "$f" ]; then
  stat -f "%N -> %Y" -- "$f"
else
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
fi
```

With `zsh` stat:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
f=the-file
zstat -LH s -- "$f"
printf '%s\n' ${s[link]:-$f}
```

Many systems also have a `readlink` command to specifically get the target of a link:

```
f=the-file
if [ -L "$f" ]; then
  printf '%s -> ' "$f"
  readlink -- "$f"
else
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
fi
```

Comment: `stat -f "%N -> %Y" -- /usr/local/bin/mvn` worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: On an old RHEL6 system, stat is of GNU coreutils 8.4 and there it's a `stat  -c %N -- /usr/local/bin/mvn`. To remove the quotations I had to pipe this into `| perl -pe 's/['"'"'\`]//g'`

Comment: @cfi `tr -d \'\\`` would be enough. Note that that RHEL system would have GNU `find` with which you'll have more control over.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `file` command.

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ ls -l mytest
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sreeraj sreeraj 15 Dec 12 09:31 mytest -> /usr/sbin/httpd

[sreeraj@server ~]$ file mytest
mytest: symbolic link to `/usr/sbin/httpd'
```

or

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ file -b mytest
symbolic link to `/usr/sbin/httpd'
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```

Also, please go read through man page of `ls` and check the options `-L` and `-H` and see if that would suffice your requirement.

Comment: @Sree - Many thanks!  I had tried the `ls` options, but not `file`.  Unfortunately, neither seems to work :(

Comment: @SHC Sorry, I assumed that you are on a `linux` box. Please add `osx` as one of your tags. That should get to the attention of `osx` users as well. I have edited the post to add the tag, but I don't have enough credits for the edit to appear immediately.

Comment: maybe check 'readlink' utility on osx.

Answer (score 2):

With a GNU `ls` at least *(and, apparently, `tcsh`'s implementation)* you can hack the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable to insert delimiters where you like *(but `tcsh`'s builtin `ls-F` doesn't do link targets - only [link flags](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#ls-F))* Usually `ls` inserts arbitrary non-printable terminal escapes based on the values stored within that environment var, but there's nothing stopping us from inserting arbitrary anything else instead. More on this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148369/52934).

For example:

```
LS_COLORS='ln=///\n:lc=:no=//:rc=:rs=:' \
\ls ~ -l --color=always | 
sed '\|///|,\|//|!d;//d'
```

That puts a string like `//` at the head of every listing *(so just before `lrwcrwx`)* and a `///\n` just before the filename of any link. `sed` then filters on line ranges - it will `d`elete every input line until it encounters `///` and from there through the next line which matches `//` it will delete lines matching `//`. So it only gets the link name and link target - regardless of intervening characters. This is because `/` can't occur in a filename - and those in any path `ls` might print will only occur singly.

See?

```
mkdir test; cd test
touch 'long


name' shortname
ln -s l* "$(printf %s.ln l*)"; ln -s s* shortname.ln

LS_COLORS='ln=///\n:lc=:no=//:rc=:rs=:' \
\ls  -l --color=always | sed '\|///|,\|//|!d;//d'
```

...which prints:

```
long


name.ln -> long


name
shortname.ln -> shortname
```

Try it yourself.

Comment: Do you know of any implementation besides modern versions of GNU `ls` that supports `LS_COLORS` that way and a `--color=always` and options after arguments? If on a GNU system, why would you  use something that convoluted when you can use `find` or `stat`? That also probably won't work if you do some `ln -s /// some-file`.

Comment: @StephaneChezales - [this](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) indicates at least that it should work similarly with a bsd `ls`. I remember reading that somewhere else months ago about `ls`s all tending to accept a termcap like syntax. Good point about the `ln -s ///` thing - but `\0`NULs work as well - and `-R`ecursively. As to why - well, it's easy to use. In some cases easier than `find` - and it seemed a little more on topic here than `find` would have been. In any case, not too many people consider it, so I mention it when I'm reminded.

Comment: See [the man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) or [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2904) for FreeBSD. If you want to test things on FreeBSD, you can use live CDs like GhostBSD/mfsbsd in a VM.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - no, i dont need to test it - definitely a [wholly different animal](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/ls/print.c#L474). If you care to look, the gnu source is also linked to in the link in this answer. i wonder where i read that other thing? thanks very much for pointing that out though, that was a mistaken assumption im happy to discard. ive edited the answer.

Comment: recent versions of `tcsh` have a `ls-F` builtin that supports `LS_COLORS` the same way as some versions of GNU `ls`, but it resorts to invoking `ls -F` if you pass any option to it, so that won't work here unless `ls` is GNU `ls` on your system.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - what do you mean by that exactly - sorry i dont follow this one...? i only wrote it in because in the same google search with which i found bsd's source i also found tcsh's env docs. theyre pretty eplicit there about how it should be used - moreso than the gnu folks - most of what the [tcsh docs say](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/ENVIRONMENT.html) i gathered from the gnu source. it seems weird they would be so explicit in a shell doc about a possibly unrelated command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - ok. so you mean `--color-always` and [`$color`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html) probably. it might still work, though, one would have to be pretty devoted to doing it. a tty in between would be necessary i guess - maybe just a `exec 3<>/dev/tty` beforehand - *(if `tcsh`will do it, classic `csh`s probably wouldnt)*. as i said before, i only wrote it up at all because it seemed relevant - and it can be handy in different ways for noting different file-types/extensions with different delims *(or different numbers of such)* especially for extensns

Comment: You need `-l` to retrieve the symlink target, so `ls-F` won't do.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - oh. duh. `ls-F` makes that obvious enough, I guess. guess it just didn't occur to me what they'd do an `ls` that didn't do `ls` stuff.

Answer (score -1):

[On Linux / Bash]

I'd do this:

```
ls -l | sed -e"s/ \+/ /g" | cut -d' ' -f 9-
```

The `sed` command collapses multiple spaces to a single space;
the `cut` extracts the 9th field onwards where the field-separator is a space.

Typical output from this:

```
libboost_atomic.a
libboost_atomic.so -> libboost_atomic.so.1.57.0
libboost_atomic.so.1.57.0
...
libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_wserialization.so -> libboost_wserialization.so.1.57.0
libboost_wserialization.so.1.57.0
```

Alternatives are:

```
ls -l | awk '{ print $9, $10, $11 }'
ls -l | awk '{ $1 = $2 = $3 = $4 = $5 = $6 = $7 = $8 = "" ; print }'
```

But those are imperfect: the first can output trailing spaces; the second, leading spaces.

Comment: The question explicitly stated "... without having to pipe through another command ..."

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Good point; I agree. I hope, though, that this is still of use to someone wanting an answer to the title question (without the detail in the description).